# Ruby on rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, devise, model

Simple basic question. In my controller,

```
  def new
    @link = Link.new
  end
```

I use devise, and following a tutorial, the new method becomes as so

```
  def new
    @link = current_user.links.build
  end
```

new and build are somewhat similar method if not mistaken, but why did the tutorial changed from Link to links? is it wrong to do current_user.Link.build?

Comment: yes its wrong cutrrent_user.links build a link associated to the current user.

Comment: The build method must be chained to the plural version of the model relationship. If you write `Link` then you're making direct reference to the model itself.

Comment: Still am quite unclear about these. What do you suggest for me to read for more understanding @SebastiánPalma ?

Comment: The [association basics](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) from the Rails documentation @akusaip.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what about these, user.links.build Can this line works @SebastiánPalma ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> new and build are somewhat similar method if not mistaken

Yes similar, but with major differences which can land you in major trouble and errors..

Firstly, `Link.new` creates a `new` instance of link with `nil` and `default` values depending on your `migration` file. Whereas, `current_user.links.build` creates the same `new` instance as above but also has an extra attribute set `user_id` to your `current_user.id`. This is only possible and tells you couple of things about `association` between `User` and `Link` e.g.

- User `has_many` links. Because, of the plural form `links`, so your question in comments `link` cannot be used unless it has a `has_one` relationship with `user`.
- `user.links.build Can this line works` NO! `current_user` is a helper provided which returns logged in user's object, if you want to use user, you may need to assign `current_user` to it.

Hope it makes sense to you. Do read [association basics](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) as suggested by @Sebastián

**UPDATE**

As mentioned in the comments, `new` and `build` are alias, as a result, you can also do the following,

```
current_user.links.new
```

Having said that, as correctly, mentioned by @Sergio Tulentsev, doing the following will throw error,

```
Link.build #wrong
```

But the other differences remain the same.

Comment: `build` and `new` are just aliases https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation.rb#L125

Comment: @Md.FarhanMemon: as mentioned in comments to Iceman's post, new and build _are_ indeed aliases, but only on relations. Something like `Link.build` won't work.

Comment: Right, ofcourse, you know it when you are coding, but miss it while putting it down in the answer, lol..thanks for pointing it out.. :)

Answer (score 0):

`build` and `new` are aliases, and so are really the same method just with different names for historical reasons, they used to have slightly different behavior in old versions of Rails.

This is basic stuff of course

```
Link.new
```

---

```
@link = current_user.links.build
```

will build a new `Link` object which automatically makes a reference to `user_id` of the current_user, so you don't have to do things like

```
@link = Link.new(user_id: current_user.id)
current_user.links << @link
```

Comment: `Link.build` won't work. That method is only available on relations, not on "standalone" instances.

Comment: What's your timezone? :)

Comment: It's 5:15 in Reykjavík now, UTC time :)